# gcc optimization: what does -O0 do?

Tags: gcc

According to the gcc online documentation, it

```
Reduce compilation time and make debugging produce the expected results. 
This is the default.
```

So is it the same as leaving out -O flag at all or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html), yes, `-O0` is the default. So it is the same as leaving out the flag completely.

Comment: Plus, you can quickly undo any other -O flags that may be on the command line (from configure or from some setting in your IDE). The last one is the one that counts.

Answer (score 0):

`-O0` is the default.  An extra note, if you want the best optimization for speed, from what I read, `-O2` is actually the best option.  I thought `-O3` was but it can cause problems, just so you know.  Also, do not turn on optimizations for debugging builds as it can break them.